# How to setup virtual environment for Google App Engine in Pycharm 2.5 on Windows 7?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

First I create a new Python virtual environment:

`File` > `Settings` > `Project Interpreter` > `Python Interpreters` > `Create Virtual Environment`

- Name: `gae`
- Location: `C:\gae`
- Base Interpreter: `Python 2.7.2`
- Inherit global site packages: `No`
- Packages: `pip`, `setuptools`, `distribute`

Then I create a new Google App Engine project that uses the virtual environment as Python Interpreter. When I run the "Hello World" project, I get this error:

```
global pdb = <module 'pdb' from 'C:\Python27\Lib\pdb.pyc'>
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named pdb 
      args = ('No module named pdb',) 
      message = 'No module named pdb'
```

What should I do to resolve this error?

**Update:** The project runs without errors using the default Python interpreter. Using the virtual environment Python interpreter causes problems.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. See if it happens with ActivePython installation and verify that C:\Python27\Lib\pdb.pyc file exists, also check your interpreter paths: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/screens/snap1366-1334926408.png.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I uninstalled Python, then installed ActivePython and tried again. The C:\Python27\Lib\pdb.pyc file exists. When I do `import pdb` in the Python shell of the virtual environment, it doesn't thrown an exception. Interpreter paths are the same as yours. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain of this, but I think the SDK sets up its own virtual environment.  At the very least, it overrides a bunch of default libraries to the ones available in the SDK.

I haven't seen anyone complain of cross contamination of python libraries.  I'd suggest, don't bother with the virtual env, it's wasting your time.

Comment: This is not really a solution, but it is what I eventually did.